# .desktop file execute error message

Tags: .desktop

I want to run a program with a specific user group and added `sg mygroup` before the command in the `Exec` line of a `.desktop` file. While I could successfully run the command in a terminal, I could not start it by clicking the menu icon (nothing happens). Is there a way to see a error message somewhere?

Comment: Can you give the whole `Exec` line?

Comment: I found an issue with escaping. Actually, the program was called but due to wrong parameters it stopped again silently. While still searching for a log file I changed the Exec to `Exec=command2 "a text parameter"`. command2 does not exist and I get no error message.

Comment: So, What is final `Exec` line? and now is it working fine?

Comment: issue 1 solved: use sg in command. issue 2 not solved: where is the error log if Exec is malformed.

Comment: I think you should revise your question by adding sufficient details.

Comment: Maybe the example was not real enough :) I have `Exec=command2 "a text parameter"` (exactly like this). This is obviously not executable. But clicking on the icon does nothing. I want to see a error message somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The output (including error messages) of applications executed directly from a GUI menu is usually redirected to a file. I say “usually” because it depends on how it's configured by the distribution and by the session startup scripts. Under Debian and derivatives, under most if not all desktop environments, the file is `.xsession-errors` in your home directories.

To watch output being added to this file, open a terminal and run

```
tail -f ~/.xession-errors
```

If this file doesn't exist, look for files that were recently modified in your home directory:

```
ls -Altr ~
```

If you can't find the session log file, try finding it in your desktop environment's documentation. If you can't find it, ask a question on this site, telling us what distribution and what desktop environment (or session manager and window manager) you use.

Comment: I checked `.xession-errors` before here are no changes. I use Linux Mint 17.3 with Cinnamon. I scanned my home with `find` and there was no file which recently changed.